# JQ / Bash How to handle whitespace in JSON response?

Tags: bash, jq

I'm making calls to Azure DevOps API, and parsing the response with jq in a bash script. The JSON response contains whitespace in the form of new lines for some reason, and jq cannot handle and parse it.

E.g., I'm logging the response and it looks like this:

```
{"configuration":{"createdBy":{"displayName":"John



Smith","url":"", ..... etc `
```

jq gives me errors like

jq: parse error: Unfinished string at EOF at line 2, column 0
jq: parse error: Invalid literal at line 2, column 0

It can't deal with the space between John and Smith

How can I clean this response up so that jq can handle it?

My script:

```
checksResponse=$(curl -s -H "$headers" -X GET "$policyChecksUrl")

for check in $(echo "$checksResponse" | jq -r -c '.value[]'); do
    echo $check
    $(echo "$check" | jq -r '.configuration.id')
done
```

More complete response: I want to select an item by the id field, e.g. 174 and get the associated status field

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "configuration": {
                "createdBy": {
                    "displayName": "John Smith",
                    "url": "https://url",
                    "_links": {
                        "avatar": {
                            "href": "https://dev.azure.com/thecompany/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/aad"
                        }
                    },
                    "id": "0eecda65-30dc-6b28-b497-8411e97df5b6",
                    "uniqueName": "js@thecompany.com",
                    "imageUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/thecompany/_api/_common/",
                    "descriptor": "aad.MGVlY2RhNjUtMzBkYy03YjI4LWI0OTctODQxMWU5N2RmNWI2"
                },
                "createdDate": "2023-01-10T14:52:24.7359941Z",
                "isEnabled": true,
                "isBlocking": true,
                "isDeleted": false,
                "settings": {
                    "minimumApproverCount": 2,
                    "creatorVoteCounts": false,
                    "allowDownvotes": false,
                    "resetOnSourcePush": false,
                    "requireVoteOnLastIteration": true,
                    "resetRejectionsOnSourcePush": false,
                    "blockLastPusherVote": false,
                    "scope": [
                        {
                            "refName": "refs/heads/master",
                            "matchKind": "Exact",
                            "repositoryId": "d416904f-641b-470a-9d"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "isEnterpriseManaged": false,
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "https://dev.azure.com/thecompany/97f88eba-ecb2-484b-ae7c-c2d43a008cea/_apis/policy/configurations/173"
                    },
                    "policyType": {
                        "href": "https://dev.azure.com/thecompany/97f88eba-ecb2fa4e907d-c16b-4a4c-9dfa-4906e5d171dd"
                    }
                },
                "revision": 16,
                "id": 173,
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/thecompany/97f88eba-ecb2-484b-ae7c-c2d43a008cea/_apis/policy/configurations/173",
                "type": {
                    "id": "fa4e907d-c16b-171dd",
                    "url": "https://dev.azure.com/thecompany/97f88eba-ecb2-484bc16b-4a4c-9dfa-4906e5d171dd",
                    "displayName": "Minimum number of reviewers"
                }
            },
            "artifactId": "vstfs:///CodeReview/CodeRev2f38956",
            "evaluationId": "0c7b74ad661353ee2",
            "startedDate": "2024-02-22T17:14:01.8987983Z",
            "status": "queued",
            "context": {}
        },
        {
            "configuration": {
                "createdBy": {
                    "displayName": "Jon Snow",
                    "url": "https://s-6ea05e3f7377",
                    "_links": {
                        "avatar": {
                            "href": "https://dev.azure.com/thecompany/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/aad.YzZhNGMDVlM2Y3Mzc3"
                        }
                    },
                    "id": "c6a4cf2d-0529-6a3d-88fb-6ea05e3f7377",
                    "uniqueName": "jonsnow@thecompany.com",
                    "imageUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/thecompany/_api/_common/identityIfb-6ea05e3f7377",
                    "descriptor": "aad.YzZhNGNmVhMDVlM2Y3Mzc3"
                },
                "createdDate": "2021-01-28T20:13:48.555187Z",
                "isEnabled": true,
                "isBlocking": true,
                "isDeleted": false,
                "settings": {
                    "requiredReviewerIds": [
                        "b4704bd8fb603d"
                    ],
                    "minimumApproverCount": 1,
                    "creatorVoteCounts": true,
                    "scope": [
                        {
                            "refName": "refs/heads/master",
                            "matchKind": "Exact",
                            "repositoryId": "d4169f-7210d2c5b1ad"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "isEnterpriseManaged": false,
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "https://dev.azure.com/thecompany/97f88ebay/configurations/174"
                    },
                    "policyType": {
                        "href": "https://dev.azure.com/thecompany/97f88eba-ecb2-8ec8-39368250530e"
                    }
                },
                "revision": 1,
                "id": 174,
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/thecompany/97f88eba-ecb2-484b-acy/configurations/174",
                "type": {
                    "id": "fd2167ab-b0be68250530e",
                    "url": "https://dev.azure.com/thecompany/97f88eba-ecb2-484b-ae7c-c2d43a008cea/_abe-447a-8ec8-39368250530e",
                    "displayName": "Required reviewers"
                }
            },
            "artifactId": "vstfs:///CodeReview/Ca%2f38956",
            "evaluationId": "8a60f138-10c8-4838-81b4-031763798fdf",
            "startedDate": "2024-02-22T17:12:38.7413814Z",
            "status": "queued"
        }
    ],
    "count": 2
}
```

Comment: It's not `jq` that can't handle the spaces, it's your `for` loop. The answer is probably to do all the processing in `jq` instead of trying to do half the processing before spitting it out into a bash string converting it back to JSON. If you have a more complete JSON example it'd be easier to create a `jq` query to do so.

Comment: For the for loop issue see: [Why you don't read lines with "for" in bash?](https://superuser.com/questions/363559/why-you-dont-read-lines-with-for-in-bash)

Comment: Why do you need a shell loop at all? Just `jq -r '.value[].configuration.id'` to get your output (minus the output of `$check` itself, but it's easy to add to the jq program – I'm not sure if that's actually needed or simply there for debugging)

Comment: Added a better response example ... every configuration item has an id and I want to select by id and get the associated status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are actually newlines in the response then @k314159 is correct and you need to fix that in the response. If the output you provided is the result of `echo $check` though then you have a different problem - word splitting is breaking your `for` loop.

Let's say the output of `$(echo "$checksResponse" | jq -r -c '.value[]')` is simply: `{"configuration":{"createdBy":{"displayName":"John Smith"}}}`. This is how bash is going to parse the `for` loop:

`for` `check` `in` `{"configuration":{"createdBy":{"displayName":"John`  `Smith"}}}`

Notice that your JSON got split into two pieces - whitespace is used for word splitting after all. That means you're only passing partial JSON snippets to `jq` inside the loop and that will never work.

The simplest fix in this case is to do all your processing in one `jq` statement:

```
printf '%s' "$checksResponse" | jq -r '.value[].configuration.id'
```

Comment: Thank you @tjm3772 ! Much appreciated. Can you help me to select the status for a specific configuration id? I left a better example above

Comment: Might be worth its own question depending on how much help you're looking for crafting queries but in the simplest case try something like `jq -r '.value[].configuration | if .id == 174 then . else empty end'`

Comment: I got it! $(echo $checksResponse | jq '.value[] | select(.configuration.id==174) | .status')

Answer (score 1):

The response is not valid JSON, because strings are not allowed to contain newlines. This is stated in https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt:

> All Unicode characters may be placed within the    quotation marks
> except for the characters that must be escaped:    quotation mark,
> reverse solidus, and the control characters (U+0000    through
> U+001F).

The newline character needs to be escaped as `"\n"`.

The reason you're getting newlines in the strings is probably because you're passing the `jq -r` flag (meaning "Output raw strings, not JSON texts").

Comment: I unfortunately have no power over Azure's reponses

Comment: @sigemer See my edit. I think it's because you're using the `-r` flag.

Comment: Removed, but didn't work .... the new lines aren't present outside of the for loop though. The response is clean before the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your question shouldn't be "how to handle whitespace in a shell loop?", but your question should be "how to extract a property based on another value from a JSON document?" instead. You don't need a shell loop here, jq is perfectly capable of extracting objects (or values) based on a condition.

```
jq -r --argjson id 173 '.value[] | select(.configuration.id == $id).status'
```

`--argjson` even allows you to capture values from "outside" in a variable to be then used in the jq program.

Comment: Program needs to be single quoted or else `$id` will be expanded (probably to nothing) before `jq` can get to it.

Comment: @tjm3772 whoops, you are absolutely correct! No idea how I ended up putting double quotes there :)

Comment: Probably, but I didn't know that was my question  - and I did learn some important knowledge about the for loop and the whitespace that it was creating! I'm sure I'm not the only person who's fallen into this issue

Comment: @sigemer yes, that's why there's already a [question and an answer](https://superuser.com/q/363559/112968) over at superuser.

Comment: @knittle right ... but I didn't know that this was my actual issue. So wouldn't have found that question.